# tikz def node name (or reference) for nodes create using the def

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, nodes

I have the following definition in order to create a node with cylinder shape

```
\def\dnc[#1,#2,#3,#4]#5{
  \node[draw, cylinder, alias=cyl, shape border rotate=90, aspect=1.6, %
  minimum height=25, minimum width=20, outer sep=-0.5\pgflinewidth, %
  color=orange!40!black, left color=orange!70, right color=orange!80, middle
  color=white] (#4) [below=of #1, xshift=#2] {};%
  \node  [below=of #1, xshift=#2, yshift=#3] {#5};%
  \fill [orange!30] let \p1 = ($(cyl.before top)!0.5!(cyl.after top)$), \p2 =
  (cyl.top), \p3 = (cyl.before top), \n1={veclen(\x3-\x1,\y3-\y1)},
  \n2={veclen(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)} in (\p1) ellipse (\n1 and \n2);
};
```

and another def which create a collection of these in a square shaped node.

```
\def \cnb[#1]#2{
  \node[computenode] (#1) {#2}; 
  \dnc[#1.west, 7mm, -3mm, a1]{$\A_1$};
  \dnc[#1.east, -7mm, -3mm, a1]{$\A_2$};
  \dnc[#1.north west, 7mm, -3mm, a1]{$\A_3$};
  \dnc[#1.north east, -7mm, -3mm, a1]{$\A_4$};
};
```

My problem is that for creating edges I am not able to refer to the node (cylinders) by there names. I get the error

> no shaped a1 is known.

Comment: A quick guess, without trying this first, is that there may be whitespace creeping into your node name.  Try not to have a space before the node name in your macro.

Comment: It would also help to include a preamble showing the packages and TikZ libraries you're using.

Comment: Turns out that the whitespace was the issue. Works fine when I closed the gap. Should I remove this posting?

Comment: You've got some typos in there and I'm not sure what they should be.  (1) in the definition of `\dnc` you have a node that has no location.  (2) your definition should probably read `\def\dnc[#1,#2,#3,#4]#5;{....}`.  Right now you've got `\def....{...};` which is not correct.   (3)  Not sure what `computenode` is supposed to be.

Comment: @Sandeep you can delete your question or flag it to let the moderators decide whether it should be deleted. I don't think this should be decided by anyone else but you or them.

Comment: Sandeep, any update? Did you decide if this should be closed? If not, maybe @A.Ellett could convert his comment(s) into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've polished the code according to the comment section and this is the result of my efforts.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pagecolor{white}
\tikzset{computenode/.style={red},
  a1/.style={blue},
  }% End of \tikzset...
\def\A{A}

\def\dnc[#1, #2, #3, #4]#5{%
  \node[draw, cylinder, alias=cyl, shape border rotate=90, aspect=1.6,%
  minimum height=25, minimum width=20, outer sep=-0.5\pgflinewidth,%
  color=orange!40!black, left color=orange!70, right color=orange!80, middle
  color=white] (#4) [below=of #1, xshift=#2] {};%
  \node[below=of #1, xshift=#2, yshift=#3] {#5};%
  \fill[orange!30] let
    \p1 = ($(cyl.before top)!0.5!(cyl.after top)$), 
    \p2 = (cyl.top), 
    \p3 = (cyl.before top), 
    \n1={veclen(\x3-\x1,\y3-\y1)},
    \n2={veclen(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)} 
     in (\p1) ellipse (\n1 and \n2);
  }% End of \dnc...

\def \cnb[#1]#2{
  \node[computenode] (#1) {#2}; 
  \dnc[#1.west, 7mm, -3mm, a1]{$\A_1$}
  \dnc[#1.east, -7mm, -3mm, a1]{$\A_2$}
  \dnc[#1.north west, 7mm, -3mm, a1]{$\A_3$}
  \dnc[#1.north east, -7mm, -3mm, a1]{$\A_4$}
  }% End of \cnb...

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\cnb[namefrom]{My cylinder!}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe, cylinder]